# Rails iterate for huge db table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have huge db table, and i need to do something with here, but how i can do this? 
if i write:

```
@person = Person.all
@person.each do |p|
//something
end
```

It's loads, loads system, and took time. Are any ways to iterate for table by not loading all data to some variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a use case to use `find_in_batches` or `find_each`.

This will load data chunk by chunk, [see doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches).

Comment: The related function [find_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) gives you a little cleaner syntax for this (it still calls find_in_batches under the hood).

Comment: @XavierHolt: depends on the needs but could be yes.

Comment: hm, how say him, for example that here reads by 5000 entries?

Comment: default is by 1000, but you can set the `batch_size` param: `find_in_batches(:batch_size => 5000)` or `find_each(:batch_size => 5000)`

Comment: @brabertaser1992: don't forget to accpet an answer

Comment: maybe i write bad code... how to use this batches? as before i write simple a = A.all a.each do.... but how do now, selecting all, and iterating, but in bathces select...

Comment: There are examples in the doc. I don't understand your pb

Comment: with find_each all is ok... but with find_in_batches i get errors///

Comment: Find each uses find_in_batches behind the scene, so don't worry! The trick here is that find in batches returns a collection, not a single element

Answer (score 0):

The best starting point for this question is probably the [Rails Guide entry Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches).

Essentially, as far as built in methods go, you can choose between `find_each` and `find_in_batches`. The former is used the same way as find (meaning it gives you one record per iteration). The latter gives you arrays of batches.

Comment: what's the added value of your answer compared to mine?